# header sortexpression

Tags: c#, gridview

the gridview column header takes the value like this from code behind
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView grid = sender as GridView;
        DataRowView tableData = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("MMMM") ;
    }
}
```

How do I sort this particular column from code behind. 
file.asp

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblMonth_1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered jQuery DataTable?

Comment: im sorry noo. i dont use jquery datatable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to go to the code behind for this.  What kind of database are you using?

Have you considered modifying your query to include another column?

```
select mydate, dateadd(m, -3, mydate) as olderdate from mytable;
```

Then you can just make your gridview field as:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="olderdate" HeaderText="Older Date" SortExpression="olderdate" dataformatstring="{0:MMM}">
    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

And mark your gridview as AllowSorting="true".

Comment: im juz binding the data to gridview which is in the form of store procedure.Consider i have 2 columns first column is the word second column is last month name[SEPTEMBER]. when i execute the store procedure the result im getting consist of the word and september. Im juz binding it to the gridview.Im using SQL

Comment: Im getting the header name from the store procedure.

Comment: Do u have any idea other then the above mentioned..?

Comment: can the sort expression be used like this..               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression='<%System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("MMM")%>' ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"
                                ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMonth_3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Can you not change the stored procedure to do the date calculation there as an additional column?

Comment: U want me to modify the stored procedure to change the field name. Is that right??

Comment: Modify the stored procedure to ADD this field "dateadd(m, -3, mydate) as olderdate".

Comment: I'll try doing that and let u know what happened, Thanks.